# Disable animations when ending search in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uitableview, animation, uisearchdisplaycontroller

A quicky: is there a way to dismiss the keyboard and the searchDisplayController without animation?

I was able to do it when the user presses "Cancel", but when the user presses the black "window thingy" above search field (only visible while the user hasn't inserted any text), the animation always occurs, even when I change the delegate functions.

Is there a way to control this, or as an alternative, to disable the user to end searching by pressing the black window?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually de-activate the search display controller to avoid the animation:

```
[self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:NO];
```

Try putting it in `- (void)viewWillDisappear` to see if that prevents the animation when navigating away from your table view.

Comment: I should've answer this question, because I kind of got to the same conclusion, but I forgot.

Anyhow, an "accepted" and a "thank you". Have a nice weekend.